# Gráfico Highchart para app

Tags: html, appybuilder

Estoy desarrollando una `app` con `appybuilder` y quiero que grafique los resultados de un cálculo, utilizó un gráfico `highchart` ya que es el que coincide con las características de lo que necesito.

Cuando utilizo valores fijos me grafica bien, el tema está cuando quiero introducir los resultados de los cálculos. Me basé en un tutorial hecho con gráficos chart, hice una prueba con ese y va bien, pero con el de `highchart` no me va.

Aclaro que mis conocimientos en el tema son muy pobres.

Trascribo el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="series-label.js"></script>
<script src="accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var   datos =  window.AppInventor.getWebViewString() ;
    datos = datos.split(",");  



    //datos111 = [[0,20],[6,1],[6,20],[13,1],[13,20],[21,1],[21,0]]; 
    datos112 = [[0,25],[8,1],[8,18],[14,0],[14,20],[21,1],[21,0]]; 
    datos113 = [[0,18],[6,1],[6,18],[12,1],[12,25],[21,1],[21,0]]; 

    datos111 = [[datos[0],[datos[1]],[[datos[2],[datos[3]],[[datos[4],datos[5]],[[datos[6],[datos[7]],[[datos[8],[datos[9]],[[datos[10],[datos[11]],[[datos[12],[datos[13]]];     


    alert (datos[5]);



    var ctx = document.getElementById("container");

    var chart1;
    chart1 = new Highcharts.chart(ctx, {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: null,
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
    text: 'Combustible en carrera'
    },
    subtitle: {
    text: 'Comparación de estrategias'
    },
    xAxis: {
    type: '',
    title: {
        text: 'Vueltas'
    }
    },
    yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Litros'
    },
    },
    tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x:0f}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },

    plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
    },

    colors: ['#FF0000', '#008000', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],

    series: [{
    name: "Equilibrada",

    data: datos111
    },
    {
    name: "PS",

    data: datos112
    },
    {
    name: "US",

    data: datos113
    }]
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Datos112 y datos113 están fijos solo a modo de prueba, para ver como queda el gráfico, mi idea es reemplazarlos por resultados de cálculos.

El `alert` funciona bien, es decir, me tira en mi `app` la ventana con el valor del cálculo, pero el gráfico no lo lee.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes unas llaves que no cierran donde deben, y tienes que asegurarte que tu variable datos tenga los valores correctos, aqui te dejo un ejemplo el cual puede acomodar a tu necesidad:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var datos = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
            datos = datos.split(",");
            //datos111 = [[0,20],[6,1],[6,20],[13,1],[13,20],[21,1],[21,0]]; 
            datos112 = [
                [0, 25],
                [8, 1],
                [8, 18],
                [14, 0],
                [14, 20],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];
            datos113 = [
                [0, 18],
                [6, 1],
                [6, 18],
                [12, 1],
                [12, 25],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];

            datos111 = [
                [0, 25],
                [8, 1],
                [8, 18],
                [14, 0],
                [14, 20],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];            
            var ctx = document.getElementById("container");
            var chart1;
            chart1 = new Highcharts.chart(ctx, {
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Combustible en carrera'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Comparación de estrategias'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: '',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Vueltas'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Litros'
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x:0f}: {point.y:.2f} m'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },

                colors: ['#FF0000', '#008000', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],

                series: [{
                        name: "Equilibrada",

                        data: datos111
                    },
                    {
                        name: "PS",

                        data: datos112
                    },
                    {
                        name: "US",

                        data: datos113
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

 <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transcribí el código que me pasaste, y modifiqué datos según los cálculos de la app, cuando dejo datos111, datos112 y datos 113 tal cual me pasaste, es decir, con valores fijos, hace bien el gráfico, el problema está cuando remplazo por los valores obtenidos de la app, en este caso el gráfico queda en blanco, como si no hubiera nada. Probé modificando solo un valor, y lo curioso es que poniendo el alert si me salta en la app el cartel con el resultado. Paso lo que probé recién:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var datos = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString() ;
            datos = datos.split(",");
            //datos111 = [[0,20],[6,1],[6,20],[13,1],[13,20],[21,1],[21,0]]; 
            alert(datos[1]);

            datos112 = [
                [0, 25],
                [8, 1],
                [8, 18],
                [14, 0],
                [14, 20],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];
            datos113 = [
                [0, 18],
                [6, 1],
                [6, 18],
                [12, 1],
                [12, 25],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];

            datos111 = [
                [0, datos[1]],
                [8, 1],
                [8, 18],
                [14, 0],
                [14, 20],
                [21, 1],
                [21, 0]
            ];            
            var ctx = document.getElementById("container");
            var chart1;
            chart1 = new Highcharts.chart(ctx, {
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Combustible en carrera'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Comparación de estrategias'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: '',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Vueltas'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Litros'
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x:0f}: {point.y:.2f} m'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },

                colors: ['#FF0000', '#008000', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],

                series: [{
                        name: "Equilibrada",

                        data: datos111
                    },
                    {
                        name: "PS",

                        data: datos112
                    },
                    {
                        name: "US",

                        data: datos113
                    }
                ]
            });
        });


</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Es decir, con este último código no aparece el gráfico pero si aparece el alert con el resultado bien hecho de datos[1]